# How to concatenate variables in cmd shell

Tags: variables, cmd, environment-variables

I am writing a cmd script. Part of what I have to do requires me to concatenate the values of two variables. I've created a variable called %mydate%, and I would like to concatenate that with a space and the value of the system variable %time%.

I've tried `set mydate2 = %mydate% %time%`, but it is null.

Any ideas?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
set mydate2=%date% %time%
```

Note: %date% and %time% are just examples - they are created by the interpreter and thus always exist.

Comment: Any ideas why it's not working for me when I do the same thing?

Comment: Spaces around the " = " are different